# When should jQuery.each() be used instead of _.each() (http://underscorejs.org/)? When should _.each() be used instead of jQuery.each()?

Tags: jquery, arrays

When should jQuery.each() be used instead of _.each() (http://underscorejs.org/)? 
When should _.each() be used instead of jQuery.each()?

any suggestions, please

Comment: One is jQuery an d the other is underscorejs. both seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.each() should be used to iterate over a jQuery object like the one containing many DOM elements as we can use the jQuery functions to manipulate them.

_.each() should to used to iterate over arrays which are not DOM objects which do not require the
jQuery functions to manipulate them.